# convert struct type to matrix octave

Tags: matlab, file-io, struct, octave, mat-file

I have a `myfile.mat` that contains `3000x35` size data. When I load it into a variable as :

```
a = load('myfile.mat')
```

It gives `struct` of size `1x1` . How can I get exact form as  matrix. This is required because I need to change certain column values.

Comment: what happens if you just do `load('myfile.mat')`? at least in Matlab, that shouldn't give you a struct, but your matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This answer is valid for MATLAB, I am not sure it works *exactly* the same way in Octave)

---

You have several options:

#### Option 1:

If the `.mat` file only contains one variable, you can do:

```
a = struct2array(load('myfile.mat'));     % MATLAB syntax
a = [struct2cell(load('myfile.mat')){:}]; % Octave syntax
```

#### Option 2:

You need to know the name of the variable at the time of saving, which is now a name of a field in this `struct`. Then you would access it using:

```
a = load('myfile.mat'); a = a.data;
```

#### Option 3 (unrecommended!):

Just remove the `a =` part of the expression,

```
load('myfile.mat');
```

Then the variables inside this file will "magically spawn" in your workspace. This is not recommended because it makes it difficult (*impossible?*) to see when certain variables are created.

Comment: For option 1, it gives me error as "error: 'struct2array'" in octave. May be it works for matlab, but not in octave.

Comment: @Shyamkkhadka I have added the equivalent Octave syntax. Give it a try!

Comment: interesting, is struct2array documented anywhere for matlab? in 2016b if I type 'help struct2array' i get a single line: "struct2array Convert structure with doubles to an array."  but I can't find anything further, so see also's for struct2cell, and searching the latest documentation on mathworks.com returns "No results for struct2array"

Comment: @NickJ the function consists of 3 lines... Just open its .m file and you'll see. :)

Comment: I do a bit of code contribution to octave, so I'll pass on peeking under the hood. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. I did like this

```
a = load('myfile.mat')
a = a.data
```

So that now I can access values of a as matrix with indexing, a(1,2) like this.
It is in octave. I hope it is similar in matlab.